# How to convert to/from an 8-bit float representation?

Tags: java, floating-point, type-conversion

I'm currently creating an emulator for a hypothetical CPU. The CPU has 16 8-bit registers which can either represent a signed byte or an 8-bit float.

Both SByte and FByte contain a byte member variable.

I currently have worked out how to get the real value of the floating byte using the following:

```
FByte = SEEEEMMM

value = (-1)^S + 1.M^(E-7)

S = Sign bit
M = Mantissa
E = Exponent
```

How would I go about converted a given double value (e.g. -3.562) into a float representation (as SEEEEMMM).

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I currently know how to do this in theory - write it in base-2 scientific notation and binary representation but to do it that way in my program would require using String manipulation whereas I'd rather keep String intermediaries out of it.

Comment: I don't see how you get String *into* it, or what your actual problem with writing the code is.

Comment: Bit hard to explain now because I'm on my phone but I had introduced Strings because of the written paper method I'd been taught this through, i.e. convert decimal to binary. 3.25 -> +11.01 (My String intermediary as I wasn't sure how to represent this with other data types), then shift the floating point and convert it into the floating byte format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic plan for converting a `double` to your float representation should be:

1. Convert the `double` to a `long` using [`doubleToLongBits`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToLongBits-double-).  This gives the IEEE 754 representation of the `double`.
2. Extract the parts of the `double` by using bit operations on the `doubleToLongBits` result.  Bit 63 is the sign bit.  Bits 62-52 are the biased exponent.  Bits 51-0 are the mantissa.
3. The upper 3 bits of the mantissa (bits 51-49 of the original float) will become your resulting 3-bit mantissa.  (There is an implied 1 in both formats.)  However, you'll have to decide how to handle rounding, if bit 48 of the original float is 1.  If bits 51-49 are `0b111` and you decide you need to round up, write your code very carefully, because now the mantissa goes from `[1].111` to `[1]0.000`, which means you will need to shift one to the right (to get `[1].000`), which will impact the resulting exponent.  (I'm using `[1]` to indicate an implied 1 bit in the mantissa.)
4. To get the new exponent, take the original biased exponent, subtract 1023, and add 7.  1023 is the bias of an IEEE 754 `double`, and 7 appears to be the bias of your floating-point type.  The result will be the new exponent, but it could be out of range.  [Also, you might have to add another 1 to the new exponent if you round up, as noted above.]
5. The sign bit of the result is the sign bit of the original `double`.  (I'm assuming that you meant the formula to be `(-1)^S * 1.M^(E-7)`, with `*` instead of `+`.)

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point for more information about the format of a `double`.